# Django CMS ImageField has display:none added in FE

Tags: django, django-cms

I have built a plugin that includes the following ImageField in the model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_feature_media_url)
```

This plugin also has the following template (which has been stripped down to remove irrelevant tags:

```
<img src="{{ instance.feature_block.image.url }}">
```

This image renders fine 9/10. However, occasionally Django decides to spit out the following HTML:

```
<img src="<correct-image-path>" width="0" height="0"
style="display: none !important;visibility: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;">
```

It seems to me that DjangoCMS really doesn't want to show this image. It's a reusable plugin and gets used over and over all across the project. Most of the time it renders fine. But I have to delete the entry in the database and do it again for it to show.

I have discussed this with members of the team and we're stumped. I have no idea why the plugin refuses to show this image.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you by any chance have an adblocker installed in your browser? Does this happen even if you disable your adblocker?

Comment: That's an incredible catch! Turns out the plugin has a title "Advertise in our magazines". Great find. Much appreciated.

https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/bow_down1.gif